# Java return statement weird behaviour

Tags: java, recursion, return

Beginner Programmer, I am currently studying recursion in Java I found something weird in GeeksforGeeks source code. I debug the source code and found the return statement as I know should stop the method but instead it skipped and incremented the variable "n" can someone explain why the return statement is behaving that way? I can't seem to find any information about this

The Link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-insertion-sort/

Source Code from GeeksforGeeks:

```
public class GFG
{
    // Recursive function to sort an array using
    // insertion sort
    static void insertionSortRecursive(int arr[], int n)
    {
        // Base case
        if (n <= 1)
            return;
      
        // Sort first n-1 elements
        insertionSortRecursive( arr, n-1 );
      
        // Insert last element at its correct position
        // in sorted array.
        int last = arr[n-1];
        int j = n-2;
      
        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
          greater than key, to one position ahead
          of their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > last)
        {
            arr[j+1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j+1] = last;
    }
     
    // Driver Method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int arr[] = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6};
      
        insertionSortRecursive(arr, arr.length);
         
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are returning from the recursive call of `insertionSortRecursive( arr, n-1 );` - after that returns the code continues.

Comment: What do you mean "it skipped and incremented n"?

Comment: Right, the `return` went to the previous call.  See where you pass `n-1` in to each call?  `n` incremented because you went to the code that called the method.

Comment: @Bohemian after the return statement it went to "int last" skipping the insertionsortrecursive(arr, n-1)

Comment: @markspace Ohhh, correct me if I'm wrong recursion works by creating a stair like stacked of methods so when you use return it returns back to the method before the last method in which variable "n" didn't increment but returned to its state before n = 1?

Comment: I'd say "the state before the `n-1` was executed."  I think you have the idea.  Remember to that `return` goes back to the statement just after the call to the method and continues executing from there.  You should give your method a simple example (like three items to sort) and try to work out the calls and returns by hand, then step through with a debugger to check your work.